# Closed-forms of definite integrals

Tags: definite-integrals, soft-question, closed-form

Am I right to think that though we have a well-established theory of integrability of functions by means closed-form expressions, we have nothing similar about definite integrals ?

For instance, the Gaussian is well-known to have no closed-form antiderivative (this is proven), but the integral from $0$ to $\infty$ is $\sqrt\pi$.

---

**Update**:

When I say closed-form for a constant, I mean a closed-form expression where only integer arguments are allowed. For example, $\pi^e$ as it equals $\arccos^{\exp(1)}(-1)$, but not $\gamma$.

Comment: "Most" integrals cannot be evaluated in "closed form," i.e. in terms of "elementary functions". See Liouville's theorem; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra). As you say the Gaussian cannot. Every definite integral is a number, so in that sense it always has a closed form. On the other hand if you mean can we always get nice quantities such as $e$ and $\pi$ from definite integrals, then the residue calculus could help, e.g. $\int_C=2\pi i\sum r_i$ where $r_i$ are the residues. Here $2\pi i$ may appear, but then again may disappear depending on $\sum r_i$.

Comment: @Antinous: in what way does Liouville's theorem (which is implicitly alluded to in my post) help ?

Comment: @Antinous: residue calculus wil help you solve some integrals when they are solvable. It will not tell you about solvability.

Comment: *One* viewpoint is to look for the anti-derivative. If the anti-derivative cannot be found in terms of elementary functions (something which Liouville's methods can help show), then the definite integral can not be evaluated in *that way* (substituting limits). Of course this doesn't rule out other approaches.

Comment: @Antinous: I know about all this. The question is about the existence of closed-forms for definite integrals, in general. The example I gave is clearly one that doesn't pass Liouville tough it has a simple closed-from.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want some kind of information that takes a definite integral (with arbitrary integrands? or restricted to some manageable class?) (over arbitrary domains? or restricted?), and determines whether there is closed-form expression, then I suspect it is rather hopeless. Or at least impressively challenging.

However you might be interested in the theory of *periods*, introduced by Kontsevich and Zagier. This is, as you ask for, a "well-established theory", but still highly active, with major conjectures, open questions, etc. In a nutshell, and slightly oversimplifying, a period is a number that is equal to the definite integral of a rational function (quotient of polynomials) with rational ($\mathbb{Q}$) coefficients, over a domain defined by polynomial inequalities with rational coefficients.

Every algebraic number is a period. $\pi$ is a period: it is the definite integral of $1$ over the domain $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$ (a polynomial inequality with rational, indeed integer, coefficients). One of the open questions is whether $e$ and $1/\pi$ are periods.

I only mentioned here the issue of deciding whether a given number is a period (i.e., equal to a definite integral of a certain form). This is by no means the only theme; e.g., structure of the set of periods, connections to algebraic geometry, etc.

See: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.2388.pdf .

Comment: MY question is more of the "what do we know about this" style, and it indeed looks tremendous in the general case (though the also challenging case of undefinite integrals was eventually settled, it seems).

Comment: This theory of periods looks very deep will address numerous cases of my question, but I wonder to what extent the values of these integrals can be obtained explicitly.